# webpage Development - JAVA, HTML, JSp and Jquery

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am doing sample webpage development, where I am using Java Servlet, HTML and JSP with javascript option.

I have welcome.jsp file which basically ask for login details. Based on the successfull login it will redirect to another JSP file called Menu.JSP

My problem is, even if user does not login and he browse menu.jsp directly
 `( http://{servername}:8080/project/menu.jsp)`  it is not redirecting the login page.

How should I design it? User should not browse menu.jsp, if he does not logged in.

Thanks
Siddu

Comment: Use session to find if user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `Servlet Filter` and map all your jsp pages which needs `authentication`.

There in the filter check weather user logged in or not.

See examples here on  [servlet tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: This is awesome example

Answer (score 0):

You could check for some kind of session the user got attached to if he visited another page before. Otherwis you can send him back or to the index page with a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You must develop a filter which redirects all not logged in users to login.jsp
For this matter, after the user login in to your site, set up a session for him and in the filter check if the session is valid

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to Authenticate before accessing any page,
do one thing as you are generating a small application in menu.jsp keep small logic for authentication, later slowly you can change the complete structure into MVC where you can achieve it fully...

hope this helps you, all the best

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not added any code, I would give you hint around how its done.

When your login, The user Object is set in session, When you log out the session is cleared.

When you are on menu.jsp page first of all you have to check if User Object is in session or not, If not you have to do the redirect code. Else you have to continue with rest of logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by checking some session attribute like session.getAttribute which you can set in your servlet if user is successfully logged in.